# Merging accounts after that one of the accounts was suspended for a week

Tags: support, reputation, account-suspension, merge-accounts

If someone has two accounts and merges them, but one of the accounts was suspended for a week...

1. Will he get the reputation that he earned in the non suspended account?
2. Will the answers and questions that he posted from his non suspended account be on his record?

Comment: Are both accounts on the same site?

Comment: Note that if one of the accounts was actually created to circumvent the suspension, it will be deleted and not merged — you are not going to keep any reputation earned by accounts created to circumvent system- or mod-imposed restrictions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Will he get the reputation that he earned in the non suspended account?

Yes. Once the suspension expires.

> 2. Will the answers and questions that he posted from his non suspended account be on his record?

Yes.

Nothing really changes for how merges work because of a suspension. I don't recall off the top of my head if you *can* merge a suspended account with another. I think so, but the suspension will be reapplied, so you'd still have to wait for it to expire before you can use the merged account. (General "you" here, not necessarily you specifically.)

Answer (score 3):

In a sense, the user got suspended not the 'account' - You might have done something bad and *getting around the ban with a second account makes it worse*. This is one of the cases having a sock isn't a bad thing.

I think the *logical* thing here is to wait (and not use both accounts) until your suspension is over, then request a merger. That way, the *intent* of the suspension is met, you've not attempted to sneak out of the suspension (good boy!) and the status of both accounts is not in doubt.

If you want to be *doubly* sure, use the un-suspended account, mod message explaining the situation *including* the suspension, promise to behave (and keep that promise!) then wait.

Typically a merger is a merger. You take ownership of any posts from the merged accounts, and accrued rep (your other question covers it). However, if you request a merger *while* suspended or after you are, with an account that's active during the suspension, its a clear sign you circumvented your suspension, and well, clearly arn't getting the sort of learning experience you should be getting. What happens due to this is up to the relevant mods I suppose.

Comment: The question is more about what actually results from a merge, not the merits of whether the accounts should exist. Working on the assumption that a user has two separate legitimate accounts (i.e. having forgotten their old details so created a new one, nothing nefarious) what happens to all the reputation and record of suspension when merged?

Comment: I'm not talking about that tho.  I figured it would be helpful to someone in this situation to realise its a good idea not to dig themselves deeper. I do have no idea what happens to the record of the suspension but it makes sense that it should carry through. Alas, we need a TPTB to shed light on that.

Comment: This does not provide the answer, this is a long comment