# What would happen if someone who is suspended created a new account and tries to have it merged it later?

Tags: discussion, support, account-suspension, merge-accounts

Let's say someone:

1. has his Stack Exchange account suspended for a year;
2. then created a new account;
3. tries to merge it with his previous account after the suspension is over.

What would happen then since it's theoretically not allowed as it defeats the purpose of the suspension.

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273626/merging-accounts-after-that-one-of-the-accounts-was-suspended-for-a-week?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requesting that the new account be merged into the old one would bring to the moderators and, more specifically, the community team that they'd created an account to evade a suspension. This could lead to one of several actions:

1. The new account could be deleted - especially if it had no or little useful content.
2. The new account could be merged into the old one. This is at the community team's discretion.
3. The account(s) could be suspended for a further period.

If the account was discovered before the suspension period was over then it would probably be deleted.

If, however, any questions asked using that account had garnered good answers then I might request that the account be merged into the suspended account. Otherwise, I'd be punishing users for answering in good faith.

Regardless, we take users evading restrictions seriously and will probably impose further sanctions on the user.